# Maven: pass property to a specific module from command line

Tags: maven

In an open-source project (Zeppelin) with multiple modules, the modules share different versions of the same dependency (jackson in this case), so they define a property for the version in each module's pom.xml, but unfortunately they share the same property name (jackson.version).

```
$ grep -rn '<jackson.version>'

lens/pom.xml:44:    <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
neo4j/pom.xml:38:       <jackson.version>2.10.3</jackson.version>
zeppelin-server/pom.xml:44:    <jackson.version>2.9.10.6</jackson.version>
```

My question is that when building the whole project, is there a way to update the jackson version for a **specific module** from **command line**? `-Djackson.version=<version>` won't do the job, because that will affect all modules.

Answer (score 1):

How I do it is to define a module specific property that has value set/evaluated from globally unique property. The globally unique property can be constructed easily by prefixing the original property with e.g. module name.

Example:

```
<properties>
  <nonunique.property>${mymodule.nonunique.property}</nonunique.property>
<properties>
```

When you run maven build, you can pass

```
-Dmymodule.nonunique.property=value
```